# Magnific Popup: open new modal from existing modal

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I am trying to implement the following:

I have login form displayed as a modal popup window (with [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) plugin). Inside this window I puted a link to open a new popup (registration form). And the problem is that as soon as user clicks on that link - the existing popup closed but new one does not appears.

The code for opeining popup:

```
  $.magnificPopup.open({
                items: {
                    src: name
                },
                type: 'inline',
                closeMarkup: '<button title="%title%" class="mfp-close">&times;</button>',
                preloader: false,
                fixedContentPos: true,
                fixedBgPos: true,
                overflowY: 'auto'
            });
```

Any suggestions please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure that you binded the click even correctly and you actually call $.magnificPopup.open second time? Consider using some simple tabs script inside popup, to switch between login/registration.

Comment: @DmitrySemenov take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/nKognito/w4koj941/. Calling `open` inside opened popup just closes it without any action.

Comment: Add event.stopPropagation(), popup thinks that clicked element is outside of bounds, because you added event listener via onclick attribute.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DmitrySemenov/w4koj941/10/

Comment: Great! Post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `event.stopPropagation()` in click event handler. Popup thinks that clicked element is outside of bounds, as you remove it after click by opening new popup.

http://jsfiddle.net/DmitrySemenov/w4koj941/10/

Answer (score 2):

```
callbacks: {
      open: function() {
        $('.new-ajax-popup-link').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
// close current popup
          $.magnificPopup.close();
          return false;
        });
      },
      afterClose: function() {
        // new popup instance
        var newAjaxPopupLink = $('.new-ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
          type: 'ajax'
      });
    // open it
        $('.new-ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup('open');
      }
}
```